# SCP from one server to another without password prompt

Tags: ssh, scp, key-authentication

What is the best way of doing `scp` from one box to the other without prompting for password?

There are two servers:

- Server A (10.152.2.10): `/home/oracle/export/files.txt`
- Server B (10.152.2.11): `/home/oracle/import/`

If I want to transfer the files using `scp` from server A to server B without being prompted to enter a password

[running this from Server A, `/home/oracle/export/`]

```
scp files.txt oracle@10.152.2.11:/home/oracle/import
```

This would prompt me for a password upon entering the command.

I understand that a keygen is required to be generated and copied to Server A. Thus [at server A]:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

This gives me two files stored in `/home/oracle/.ssh`:

```
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
```

1. Am I supposed to copy the two files (`id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub`) over into server B `/home/oracle/.ssh` ?

While doing some google search on this, some articles mentioned about appending/concatenating this to authorized_keys.

2. Am I supposed to create this file on my own?

I seem to be confused on what is the right way to do this.

Btw, the two servers are running Suse Linux Enterprise Edition 9...

Comment: Try 'keychain':  http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/keychain/

Answer (score 16):

1. No, you keep `id_rsa` to yourself; however, `id_rsa.pub`, which is your public key, may be copied to servers to which you wish to have access. Concatenate them onto the end of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
2. Yes, you may create `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` if it is not already created; otherwise, just append to the end of the file, using `cat id_rsa.pub >>~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Answer (score 11):

Also there is a tool that sorts all this for you called `ssh-copy-id`.

It will append the key in your agent if you have one running to the `authorized_keys` file and create it if it does not exist with the right permissions. If you aren't running an agent you can specify the key to push with `-i`: `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 5):

You should also check the permissions on the various files and directories:

```
authorized_keys needs perms of 600 (chmod 600 authorized_keys)
the .ssh directory should be 700
your home directory should be at most 744
```

Your home directory must not be writable by anyone other than you.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:

> On the client:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
ssh-copy-id oracle@10.152.2.11
```

This copys the key from the client to the server. You will need the password of the server to make it add your key to its ring.

- Password Authentication either needs to be on or you need to hand deliver the keyfile to the server.

> On the Server:

I would at the vary least, turn off Password Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

In case you configure the key generated from `ssh-keygen` but still password less transfer doesn't work, then verify the public key used on source machine in verbose mode command as below:

```
sftp -v -oPort=22 userid@server
```

Usually it refers to public key at `/home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
which might be different from one you generated using `ssh-keygen`. You need to add this `id_rsa.pub` at destination server.