# Copying files from one machine to another without asking for password

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

I am currently using this command. I am on another machine (ip1)

```
scp file.txt root@ip2:/home/praveen/test.c /home/praveen
```

The command will prompt for password.

I use it in some shell scripts, and am calling these scripts from some crontab files. 
So, I can not enter the password every time. Is there any way to disable password asking or some another way to input password from somewhere, so that I don't need to enter it again.

And I cannot use `ssh-keygen`, because I have to do the actions for these scripts only. When I use `ssh-keygen`, it will never prompt me for password again. I don't want this. Rest of the things should work as usual.

Comment: You need to configure public/private key authentication for your host/client.

Comment: See this Q&A for tips and resources on how to setup public/private key auth: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47723/how-to-setup-password-less-ssh-with-rsa-keys

Comment: possible duplicate of [SCP from one server to another without password prompt](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14196/scp-from-one-server-to-another-without-password-prompt)

Comment: You asked this question in toolbox.com later and you got the answer I think.

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the OP specifically mentions that s/he does not want to use `ssh-keygen`.

Answer (score 2):

It was not clear why you could not use `ssh-keygen` and the subsequent key exchange. I believe this is the recommended practice.

An alternative would be to use the `expect` command ([online man pages](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect)). This can eliminate user intervention in the interactive processes. As the name suggests, it expects a prompt, and responds accordingly as specified to it.

Look at this solution of [automating SSH using `expect`](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/security/expect-ssh-login-script/). To quote a few lines:

> ```
> # Look for passwod prompt
> expect "*?assword:*"
> # Send password aka $password
> send -- "$password\r"
> ```

The second line specifies the prompt that appears. In this case, it asks for password. The fourth line sends the password to the server.

Comment: +1. Never heard of `expect`. Learned sth!

Comment: This also leaks the password in the clear, just like Christos' answer. As @Barun is most definitely aware and just trying to answer your question, any method other than public/private keys is a bad idea.

Comment: This means writing the password in a file, which is even worse than having a passwordless private key.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ftp, if that's allowed on the remote server. Here's a sample of shell script I used for this purpose

```sh
HOST='remote.server.com'
USER='domainname/usrid'   
PASSWD='p@@ssw0rd'
cd /path/to/local/directory/containing/the/file/to/be/transferred
`ftp -n $HOST <<END_SCRIPT
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd /diretory/on/remote/server
put file2transfer.dat 
bye    
quit
END_SCRIPT`
```

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody posted an actual answer.

Yes, as denoted in the comments. You need to a create public/private keys pair.

Here are 2 manuals:

- [http://www.ece.uci.edu/~chou/ssh-key.html](http://www.ece.uci.edu/%7Echou/ssh-key.html)
- https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

You then can utilize `ssh-agent` to load the keys into memory, in that way you don't have to enter the password you specified for the keys - since they get stored in memory for the current session. You don't have to set a password in first place, but I would recommend to do so, since persons holding your private key could use it to compromise you.

---

Of course you can delete the keys afterwards or delete your public key from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote host. He will then prompt you for pw again.

Answer (score -1):

A simple solution is:

```
echo "password" | scp -r myfile user@remotehost:/home/user/destination
```

Comment: Indeed simple. But I don't know where OP works, or if it's private. But having the pw in plaintext in a script or even in his command history seems a little bit unsecure.

Comment: Yes this works, but it's a bad idea. The password is sent in the clear, better to use public/private keys!

Comment: Does it work?  Most things that prompt for a password directly use the users tty, which is part of why `expect` was created in the first place.  That is beyond the fact that it's a bad idea to start with.